# How to execute multiple queries/IO operation sequentially inside for loop in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, for-loop, synchronization

I've similar CONCEPT code in my application which actually consume data via Rabbit MQ and send it through event Emitter. I want to process the data in sequential manner so I've inherited the async/await functionality to my application. However it's not running in order, here's the similar example code.

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const pool = mysql.createPool({ host: 'localhost', user: 'root', database: 'sample' })
const promisePool = pool.promise();

const events = require('events');
const em = new events.EventEmitter();

setInterval(() => {

    let data = [{
        queData: [{
            clientId: 1,
            device_id: 39,
            latitude: -32.0863994,
            investigation_id: 40,
            longitude: 115.9153126
        }],
        commit: () => {
            console.log("DONE")
        }
    }]

    data.forEach(element => {
        em.emit('NEW_EVENT', element);
    });
}, 1);

em.addListener('NEW_EVENT', async (qResult) => {


    let dataArray = qResult.queData[0];

    const [rows, fields] = await promisePool.query("SELECT * FROM geo_data WHERE investigation_id = ? ", [dataArray.investigation_id]);
    console.log("RESULT - 1");
    for (let value of rows) {

        let [rows2, fields2] = await promisePool.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE geo_id = ? ", [value.id]);
        console.log("RESULT - 2");

        let [rows3, fields4] = await promisePool.query("SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE id = ? ", [rows2.user_id]);
        console.log("RESULT - 3");

        console.log("INSIDE LOOP AFTER ALL QUERY");
    }
    console.log("ALL QUERIES ARE DONE");
});
```

And here's the out put log:

```
RESULT - 1
RESULT - 2
RESULT - 1
RESULT - 1
RESULT - 1
RESULT - 3
INSIDE LOOP AFTER ALL QUERY
RESULT - 2
RESULT - 2
RESULT - 2
RESULT - 1
RESULT - 1
RESULT - 2
RESULT - 3
INSIDE LOOP AFTER ALL QUERY
RESULT - 3
INSIDE LOOP AFTER ALL QUERY
RESULT - 3
INSIDE LOOP AFTER ALL QUERY
RESULT - 2
RESULT - 2
RESULT - 2
RESULT - 3
INSIDE LOOP AFTER ALL QUERY
RESULT - 3
INSIDE LOOP AFTER ALL QUERY
RESULT - 2
RESULT - 1
RESULT - 2
RESULT - 3
INSIDE LOOP AFTER ALL QUERY
RESULT - 1
RESULT - 3
INSIDE LOOP AFTER ALL QUERY
RESULT - 2
RESULT - 2
RESULT - 3
INSIDE LOOP AFTER ALL QUERY
RESULT - 2
RESULT - 3
INSIDE LOOP AFTER ALL QUERY
RESULT - 2
RESULT - 1
RESULT - 2
RESULT - 2
RESULT - 3
INSIDE LOOP AFTER ALL QUERY
RESULT - 3
INSIDE LOOP AFTER ALL QUERY
ALL QUERIES ARE DONE
```

What I expected is

```
RESULT - 1
RESULT - 2
RESULT - 3
INSIDE LOOP AFTER ALL QUERY
ALL QUERIES ARE DONE
RESULT - 1
RESULT - 2
RESULT - 3
INSIDE LOOP AFTER ALL QUERY
ALL QUERIES ARE DONE
RESULT - 1
RESULT - 2
RESULT - 3
INSIDE LOOP AFTER ALL QUERY
ALL QUERIES ARE DONE
```

How can I execute this sequentially? I tried foreach/Map nothing actually helped.

Any feedback would highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `NEW_EVENT` handler to only run once the last handler has finished:

```
let lastProm = Promise.resolve();
em.addListener('NEW_EVENT', (qResult) => {
    lastProm = lastProm.then(async () => {
      let dataArray = qResult.queData[0];

      const [rows, fields] = await promisePool.query("SELECT * FROM geo_data WHERE investigation_id = ? ", [dataArray.investigation_id]);
      console.log("RESULT - 1");
      for (let value of rows) {

          let [rows2, fields2] = await promisePool.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE geo_id = ? ", [value.id]);
          console.log("RESULT - 2");

          let [rows3, fields4] = await promisePool.query("SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE id = ? ", [rows2.user_id]);
          console.log("RESULT - 3");

          console.log("INSIDE LOOP AFTER ALL QUERY");
      }
      console.log("ALL QUERIES ARE DONE");
    });
});
```